# Need to reduce the zooming level of the image

Tags: css, magento

please visit [link1](http://hotwheelstoys.in/4/em0113-full-package/index.php/electronics/nokia-2610-phone.html) you can see image is zooming too much ,

but here [link2](http://hotwheelstoys.in/2/em0113-full-package/index.php/electronics/nokia-2610-phone.html) its fine. how to display link 1 image  as like link2

code for link 1 :

```
<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')); ?>
```

code for link 2 :

```
<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($_product->getImage()); ?>
```

for some reason we can't replace the code2 by code1

Answer (score 0):

It's not a zoom problem, it's your image dimensions creating problem ,

in first page u are using image with 566x738(portrait size) and compressing it to square dimensions of 350x350.

on second page you are using image with same size and mainly with same aspect ratio 1:1 required by your css rules, and that is 350x 350

Comment: can you please give me code that can fix it in link2.

Comment: @user9999 or other way , u should fix code one as i m guessing its using the same uploaded pic which is not a good idea when it comes to web symmetry. Anyways we can't help because it depends on your image/media configuration for cropping , resizing and alias names.